# How to integrate MailChimp with Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, mailchimp

**I'm trying to integrate my Flutter app (iOS & Android) with [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com). There's no MailChimp package that directly support Flutter.**

Basically I need to setup some custom 'events' to auto-Tag users with a Mailchimp Tag based on their behaviour/Events, as follows:

When a user has successfully registered their account on the App for the first time (with their Firstname, Lastname and Email), I need to log this Event with the SDK and auto-tag the user with this exact tag name as follows: Registered_User

When a user successfully adds and completes all Child profile details/requirements during onboarding, they will need to be auto-tagged with Child_Added

When a user successfully adds their first child Milestone they will need to be auto-tagged with First_Child_Milestone_Completed

When a user successfully adds their second child Milestone they will need to be auto-tagged with Second_Child_Milestone_Completed

I've asked ChatGPT the following question:

> How to integrate MailChimp Mobile SDK with flutter

The answer:

> As of my last knowledge update in January 2022, MailChimp does not
> have an official Mobile SDK for Flutter. However, you can still
> integrate MailChimp functionality into your Flutter app using the
> MailChimp API.

Is there any other solution but the MailChimp apis?

Comment: I asked ChatGPT "Complete the sentence factually correct: The chancellor of Germany is...". The answer: "The chancellor of Germany as of my last knowledge update in January 2022 was Angela Merkel. However, since I don't have real-time updates, I recommend checking the most recent and up-to-date sources for the current chancellor of Germany as it might have changed after my last update." vs. Wikipedia "Olaf Scholz is a German politician who has been serving as the chancellor of Germany since 8 December 2021."